# Discord.JS setInterval - Embed Message Problem

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I encounter a problem with message.channel.send which message is not defined. I have tried many ways but still, I'm confused. Could you help me a bit? Thanks!

```
    client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("Ready");
    client.user.setActivity("Games");
  
    var customChannel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === "853390548495106078");
  


        setInterval(() => {
        const customChannel = new Discord.MessageEmbed()

        .setColor("#00bfff")
        .setTitle("Example")
        .setDescription("**Follow us on instagram.")
        .setFooter("Created and Developed by InNovAqua ❤️");
        
        message.channel.send(customChannel)
  }, 5000); //86400000 ->24h
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you get the specific channel from the client, the you overwrite it with the embed. I think that what you wanted to do is:

```js
client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("Ready");
    client.user.setActivity("Games");
  
    var customChannel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === "853390548495106078");
  


    setTimeout(() => {
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("#00bfff")
            .setTitle("Example")
            .setDescription("**Follow us on instagram.")
            .setFooter("Created and Developed by InNovAqua ❤️");
        
        customChannel.send(embed)
  }, 5000); //86400000 ->24h
});
```

Comment: it's the same problem, it doesn't work either

Comment: customChannel.send(embed)
                              ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

Comment: could you please tell me if logging the value of customChannel just before the setInterval, outputs `undefined` or the correct object? thanks

Comment: I have changed it to this and it doesn't show any error. The problem is that setInterval doesn't work -> https://sourceb.in/YWCuYISFOG

Comment: In the way you have just done, a message is sent to that channel every time a message, in any guild where the bot is a member, and every five seconds another is sent until the bot is stopped. I think that what you wanted is setTimeout, with executes the function once after the time you tell it.

Comment: Could you help me with the code because I'm struggling enough?

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do? This would allow me to help you more effectively.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233543/discussion-between-sintuz-and-innovaqua).